# A problem with convert yolov8 recognition sys to exe by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, yolov8

I use Pyinstaller with Python 3.9.13,when i use this commend "pyinstaller interface.py --onefile -w"
to convert the project to exe file ,I have this problem :

[it is can not find ultralytics\yolo\..etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqyMQ.png)

[it is can not find ultralytics\yolo\..etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCW5t.png)

when I removed --onefile flag, there is no  ultralytics folder with other libs.
any help?

Note : I use resource_path() function.

Comment: create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and found a similar question on ultralytic's github discussions section. There, the answer of the user "dh031200" on March 15 in this [link](https://github.com/orgs/ultralytics/discussions/1356#discussioncomment-5318188) helped me to solve this problem. The 5 steps this user describes can solve your problem too. There, only at step 1 change "install from source pip install -e '.[dev]'" to "install from source pip install -e .[dev]", i.e. the quotation marks around .[dev] should be removed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).